# How to fetch API data and show that on table form in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here is my code I'm not getting how to show data on the page. When I tried I got nothing on the page and it shows:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop.

Here is my Code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state = {
        data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() 
    {
      fetch("https://blockchain.info/ticker").
        then((Response) => Response.json()).
          then ((findresponse)=>
            {
              console.log(findresponse)
              this.setState({
                data: [findresponse]
                  });
            }) 
    }

    render() 
    {
      return(
        <div>
          {
            this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) =>
              <div>
                <span>{dynamicData.key}</span>
              </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How does `findresponse` look like? Do you need brackets here `data: [findresponse]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a react warning.

As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when
>   creating lists of elements.

You are having an issue accessing the data returned from bitcoin as you have an array of objects. To access the data being returned from the API you need to do something like the following:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://blockchain.info/ticker").
      then(response => response.json()).
      then(findresponse => {
        this.setState({
          data: [findresponse]
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) => {
            let keys = Object.keys(dynamicData);
            let d = dynamicData;
            return keys.map(data => {
              return (
                <div style={{borderBottom: '1px solid black'}}>
                  <p>Currency: {data}</p>
                  <p>Buy: {dynamicData[data].buy}</p>
                </div>
              );
            });
          })
          
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In that bitcoin API,  what key I should give

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong at all with your code or is it just a question about the `warning` message? If that's the case, whenever you map through an array in React, you have to give them a `key` prop. This is helpful so React knows which items have changed, updated or even added in the future.

```
// Key here stands for dynamicData's index in the array and not its key prop.
this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) =>
  <div key={Key}>
    <span>{dynamicData.key}</span>
  </div>
)
```

I suggest you to rename it from `Key` to `index` so you don't confuse keys within your code.

```
this.state.data.map((dynamicData, index) =>
  <div key={index}>
    <span>{dynamicData.key}</span>
  </div>
)
```

For more information about `keys` in React, I suggest you to read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) link.